# Idiomatic implementation of shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out the most idiomatic implementation of the react lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate`. I feel that I, and possibly others, don't utilize this method to the extent it could be because it is optional.

Generally I want to check if if the `props` or `state` of an object has changed between updates.

This does not work as this equality is pointing at the object reference:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.props !== nextProps;
}
```

So then we go down the rabbit hole of object cloning, which seems like a little bit of an ugly solution:

```
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nextProps));

 // lodash cloning method
 return _.cloneDeep(this.props) !== _.cloneDeep(nextProps);
```

Another possibility is using an immutable library like [immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), but that is another dependency I'm not sure I want to add to the project, and another API to learn.

Am I missing something? Is there a more concise approach to this?

Comment: The most concise is definitely ImmutableJS, everything else isn't going to be simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [React's shallow compare](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html) to compare props and states.

Hope this helps!